# Azure storage account key updation using RM module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm

I am trying to setup a powershell code which would update the storage account credentials every once in a while and below is the script that I have come across and it works perfectly fine.

```
function setupContext(){
    Add-AzureRmAccount
    Save-AzureRmContext -Path “path\to\json\file” 
}

#setupContext
Import-AzureRmContext -Path “path\to\json\file”
$subscriptionId='***********************************'
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
$resourceGroup="**************"
$storageAccountName="******************"
$BLOBKey= New-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName -KeyName key2 
Write-Host "BLOB Key:"$BLOBKey.Keys[0]
```

The above code does the required work, however it requires us to login to the azure-rm account which basically defeats the idea of automating this process since I would need keep updating this generated profile.

Note: I am not allowed to use az module as of now since the environment in which I work has some .NET version limitations.

So if there any other solution which could overcome the azure rm login issue, please suggest.

Comment: so what you are asking is that anyone without any access control can reset your storage account keys))). makes sense

Comment: This script would be placed at a location and only handful amount of people can access it. Hence it shouldn’t be a problem when it comes to that @4c74356b41

Comment: yeah, right. how would it work though?

Comment: @JoyWang I am not using the Azure runbook which is why I am getting the below error. `No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint `

Answer (score 0):

Use Azure Automation. This automatically sets up something called **RunAs** account. Which simply said is just **Azure AD Service Principal**.

Then assign this principal privileges on the storage account just like any other user and you are done.

And in the Automation Runbook do

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -Tenant $connection.TenantID `
    -ApplicationID $connection.ApplicationID  `
    -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint

$AzureContext = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $connection.SubscriptionID

... run rest of the code ...
```

If you want to run this from outside of Azure like on-prem server then set up manually service principal. Here is guide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

And just log into this app from powershell instead of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you want to use a non-interactive way to do that automatically. To access the azure resource with a non-interactive way, your best option currently is to use the service principal(AD App).

An Azure service principal is an identity created for use with applications, hosted services, and automated tools to access Azure resources.

The other reply is for azure automation runbook, you could follow my steps to automate it in other places else.

1.[Create an Azure Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) and [create a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret) for the app, save the secret and [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in).

2.Navigate to the storage account(or the subscription which the storage account located) in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search your service principal(AD App) with name and add it as a role(e.g. `Owner`/`Contributor`) -> `Save`.

**Note**: To give the role, you need to use an account which is an `Owner` of the  specific scope(storage account/subscription).

3.Then use the script as below, replace the specific properties with the values in `step 1`.

```
function setupContext(){
    $azureAplicationId ="<application id>"
    $azureTenantId= "<tenant id>"
    $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<client secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
    $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
    Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal 
    Save-AzureRmContext -Path “path\to\json\file” 
}

#setupContext
Import-AzureRmContext -Path “path\to\json\file”
$subscriptionId='***********************************'
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
$resourceGroup="**************"
$storageAccountName="******************"
$BLOBKey= New-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName -KeyName key2 
Write-Host "BLOB Key:"$BLOBKey.Keys[0]
```

Besides, if you want to learn more about the service principal, you could take a look at this link - [Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as the answer. Or any concern let me know. thanks.

Comment: We are checking this solution currently.

Comment: @sanketh well, good luck, if it works, don't forget to come back and accept it.;-)